# Boolean function always returns true c++

Tags: c++, function, boolean, return-value

I have a public function `validInfixCheck()` that calls private function `isBalanced()`.

The `isBalanced()` function should return false if the string has something other than + - * / or a digit. The issue that I'm having is that `isBalanced()` is ALWAYS returning true. The logic works fine if I have all the code under the same file, but not when I have an .h and .cpp.

For Example, if I enter 2^(3+4) the function should return false because `^` is not valid but right now it is returning true.

g++ calculatorMain.cpp CalculatorExp.cpp

```
Enter infix expression to evaluate:
2^(3+4)
This is what you entered: 2^(3+4)
expression is well formed
```

calculatorMain.cpp

```cpp
#include "CalculatorExp.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//prototype declarations
string getInfixExpression();

int main()
{
    CalculatorExp calc; 
    string inputExpression;
    inputExpression = getInfixExpression();

    cout<<"This is what you entered: "<< inputExpression <<endl;

    calc.validInfixCheck(inputExpression);

    return 0;
}

string getInfixExpression()
{
    string exp;
    cout<<"Enter infix expression to evaluate: "<<endl;
    cin>>exp;

    return exp;
}
```

CalculatorExp.cpp

```cpp
#include "CalculatorExp.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack> 

using namespace std;

CalculatorExp::CalculatorExp()
{
  //default constructor 
}
// public //

// valid input
bool CalculatorExp::validInfixCheck(string inputExpression)
{
    // Checks string is well formed
    if(isBalanced(exp))
    {
    cout << "expression is well formed" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "expression is NOT well formed" << endl;
    }

    // Check string has balanced ( )
    //...

    return 0;
}

// private //
bool CalculatorExp::isBalanced(string exp)
{
        int expLength = exp.length();
        bool balancedSoFar = true;
        int i = 0; // Tracks character position in string

        while(balancedSoFar && i < expLength)
        {
            char ch = exp[i];
            i++;
            if(!isdigit(ch))
            {

            switch (ch)
            {

                case '+':
                balancedSoFar = true;
                break;

                case '-':
                balancedSoFar = true;
                break;

                case '*':
                balancedSoFar = true;
                break;

                case '/':
                balancedSoFar = true;
                break;

                case '(':
                balancedSoFar = true;
                break;

                case ')':
                balancedSoFar = true;
                break;

                default:
                balancedSoFar = false;
                break;
            }
            }
        }
        if(balancedSoFar)
        {
            return 1;
            // cout << "exp is balanced" << endl;
            // Probably run the check braces function here
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
            // cout << "exp is not balanced" << endl;
            // Probably run the program to enter a new exp again
        }
}  // end isBalanced
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. There is a bunch of code here that likely has nothing to do with your problem which can be easily removed from the question.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your `isBalanced()` function one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables it uses, and observe how they change, and how the function makes its logical decisions, what observations did you make regarding how the function arrives at its return value? Your debugger will tell you that, exactly. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. You can easily figure out the anwer to what's happening in there, all by yourself, simply by using the debugger you already have.

Comment: Are you certain that's where the problem is? Here is your function in isolation with a test harness and my own version of isBalanced to compare against. They both produce the same result, and that result disagrees with your example. http://ideone.com/c71hRI I suggest breaking your program into smaller isolated cases and testing each individually. Then, when you find the parts that don't work, step through those in the debugger to find out why.

Comment: `balancedSoFar = false;
                break;` I think you just want to `return false` here. The `balancedSoFar` variable is just set to true on the next `(`., so true is returned in the if below. The logic is flawed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja interesting... when I change my switch-case to how you are doing it I only get in return `false`

Comment: Your code is checking every character in the string, not returning when it finds an invalid character.   The return value corresponds to the last character in the string, which for `"2^(3+4)"` will be the last `')'`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause is a minor logic error that could be easily found with a debugger or simple code inspection.

Comment: I used your code snippet, added a class declaration for CalculatorExp, fixed the wrong function parameter naming in CalculatorExp::validInfixCheck to get it built. Result: works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the code

```
// valid input
bool CalculatorExp::validInfixCheck(string inputExpression)
{
    // Checks string is well formed
    if(isBalanced(exp))
    {
```

Here, your method has an argument `inputExpression`, but then you test the (unrelated) string `exp` to see if it is balanced.  So this probably won't compile, unless you have a member `exp` which is an empty string -- in which case it will test the empty string which will return true...